# Find lines which contain a specific word

Tags: python

First of all I have done a great research and tried many approaches to look for solution but maybe I am doing it wrong and was not able to find a solution.

My data:
https://knsim.com/test.txt

The problem is that I want to fill all the occurrence of 'Idea_Print' in a new file (not just the name 'Idea_Print' but the complete line of log.

I have tried many approaches but had not success.

My recent code:

```
file = open(filename, 'r')
for line in file:
    if 'Idea_Print' in line:
        print(line)
```

But this didn't work for me. I even tried using re but no success.

Thanks for help.

Comment: what happened when you ran your code? did it produce an error, produce no output, or incorrect output?

Comment: no error no result. Nothing.

Comment: Check the file encoding

Comment: There's no `Episode_20` in your file.

Comment: just updated the file sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried running your code with my setup and it worked fine. Most likely, you are using the wrong filename in `open()`.

In `file = open(filename, 'r')`, make sure that `filename` is the exact same name as your saved data, including extension. Ensure that the file you are trying to access is in the same folder as your python file. If it is not in the same folder, try including the full path to the file.

Also, at the end of your program make sure you call `file.close()` to allow other programs to access it correctly.

Another thing that could be causing problems is that your variable is called `file`. This is a built-in name in Python, so you probably don't want to overwrite it. Try changing it to something like `data_file`.

Edit: Looking at that file it appears that there is a space between every character. That means you will need to use 'E p i s o d e _ 2 0' instead of 'Episode_20'. However, it appears that even that does not appear in the file. Maybe you should double-check that it is the text that you are looking for.

Comment: Dude, could you please try with this file and query for any of the episode name : https://knsim.com/test.txt

Comment: Thanks a lot man really appreciate that. Kindly change the answer so if someone else need it can take help of it. Thanks again

Comment: @JaskaranSingh Happy to help! To see the spaces, I just opened in Notepad and saw that the letters were far apart.